# drilling and putting a wall plug into spackle, taped up dry wall

Tags: spackling-paste

hi i recently tried to put up some curtain rails and unfortunately whilst drilling have put a much larger hole and made a mess of the wall, now i need that same area to put the curtain rails on, can i put spackle into the large hole together with the path/tape and then redrill into the hole with a wall plug? will it be stable? thanks for the answers in advance i presume its an insanely novice question

Answer (score 2):

Only the lightest of curtains should be hung with hollow-wall anchors in the first place, even if you use togglers (anchors with mechanically-deployed wings). Screw-in or expanding drive-in anchors are almost guaranteed to fail after a short time, and heavy or frequently manipulated curtains should be mounted into framing.

To your question, if you fill the hole well with setting-type joint compound, which is much harder and stronger than "spackle" (a rather vague term leaving much room for confusion), and then you carefully drill for a toggle anchor, you'll probably be ok.

Answer (score 2):

Spackle is just a cosmetic fix; you do not want to put any weight on it.

You should repair the wall with a small piece of drywall, or use toggle bolts to secure your curtain rod. They need larger holes anyway, so you wouldn't necessarily need to repair anything.